# TOR hidden service: PHP sessions

Tags: php, session, cookies, tor

If someone was making a **TOR** hidden service using **PHP**, **Apache**, and **MySQL**, would **sessions** have to be done differently?

Considering that many different users could be coming from the same IP address (using the same exit node), how does that change things?

Should I rely on setting client-side **cookies** that expire after a certain time period once logged in? Should I be checking **cookies** to see if they are logged in instead of **$_SESSION**?

I have searched high & low on here and Google and can't seem to find anyone else asking this question.

I have read the **TOR** documents on configuring a hidden service, how **TOR** works, etc.

Comment: Sessions *do* use client side cookies (if you are sane that is), so this kinda renders this question moot.

Comment: Are you having issues with this because PHP sessions work by setting a cookie on the users computer?

Comment: I misunderstood sessions I guess. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default PHP sessions work perfectly well with TOR. There is no need to change anything.

All other questions are not related to TOR, but are subject to the usual considerations when using sessions. Do you want a login to expire after a certain inactive time? If yes, you have to implement that yourself.